# python local host http://127.0.0.1:5000/ not refreshing to new request from flask

Tags: python, flask, python-3.5, atom-editor

At the first time when I'm running the below code in Python, it's succesfully running in localhost by displaying `hello`, I'm using the atom editor.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_wrld():
   return "hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

But when I'm changing my return to `hello python` as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def dhineTrend():
   return "hello python"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

It's running in localhost but when I'm hitting the browser it keep on showing old `hello`. How to overcome it?

**Note:** After first run I cut the run, then only request the second.

Comment: Use code tags to show your code properly

Answer (score 3):

Enable `DEBUG` to auto reload files on change,

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```

There are multiple ways to do this,

```
app.config.update(DEBUG=True)
```

Or

```
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

Or, Create a `config.py` defining all the Flask settings

```
app.config.from_object('config')
```

Comment: Even I tried this earlier but getting same response. My new data is not reflecting in browser

Comment: @DhineshPazanisamy Did you stop and restart the Flask application after enabling `DEBUG`?

Comment: Yea I did but getting same response,  can  anyone say where the issue occur.